# How to set a job to manual based on previous stage failure?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline, after the stages.
At the end of last two stages as you see below.

[image]

Teardown will delete the application from kubernetes and destroy will be delete the kubenretes cluster and other resources as a whole.

I have set automatic and allow failure true.

But, I want to set the last destroy stage as manual if the teardown stage fails.So that I could cross check and resume the job later.
If the teardown passed successfully then it should be done automatically.

How to set that?

Answer (score 7):

Because, .gitlab-ci.yml does not allow rules `when: on_failure` and `when: manual` at the same time and same job rule. so I was used [Parent-child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#examples) to solve the problem.

this is a example:

1. create a cleanup job template like:

```yaml
# file name: cleanup_job_tmpl.yml

.cleanup job tmpl:
  script:
    - echo "run cleanup job"
```

2. create auto cleanup job

```yaml
# file name: cleanup_auto.yml

include: cleanup_job_tmpl.yml

cleanup job auto:
  extends: .cleanup job tmpl
  before_script:
    - echo "auto run job"
```

3. create manual cleanup job

```yaml
# file name: cleanup_manual.yml

include: cleanup_job_tmpl.yml

cleanup job manual:
  extends: .cleanup job tmpl
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - echo "manual run job"
```

4. and finally .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
stages:
  - "teardown"
  - "cleanup"

default:
  image: ubuntu:20.04

teardown job:
  stage: teardown
  script:
    - echo "run teardown job and exit 10"
    - exit 10
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: cleanup.env  

cleanup trigger auto:
  stage: cleanup
  when: on_success #(default on_success)
  trigger:
    include: cleanup_auto.yml

cleanup trigger manual:
  stage: cleanup
  when: on_failure
  trigger:
    include: cleanup_manual.yml
```

when `teardown job:` exit 10, will trigger `cleanup trigger manual` job, and when I remove `teardown job:` exit 10, will trigger `cleanup trigger auto` job.

There is my GitLab repo to demo this case.

- [manual-job-on-previous-stagefailure · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/tree/manual-job-on-previous-stagefailure)
- When success to autl run job - pipeline: [Success Pipeline · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/573235762)
- When failure to manual run job - pipeline: [Failure Pipeline · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/demo-workshop/tryci/-/pipelines/573235856)